# Tkinter .destroy() button causes error when in function

Tags: python, button, tkinter, destroy

I have a button in my Tkinter window that, when clicked, needs to call two functions: a `.get()` to store the entry box value and a `.destroy()` so the window closes when button is pressed.

I must be doing something wrong because whether I put the `.destroy()` in my grouped function with `.get()` or put `.destroy()` as the sole command in the button, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'GuardianLocator' object has no attribute 'frame'
```

I believe my code is near identical to other answers on this site so I'm not sure why `.destroy()` isn't working...

```
from tkinter import *


class GuardianLocator:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self._name = ""
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        master.title("GUARDIAN LOCATOR")

        self.locator_label = Label(frame, text="Which Sailor Guardian are you looking for?", width=40, height=2)
        self.locator_label.grid()

        self.entry = Entry(frame)
        self.entry.grid()

        self.button1 = Button(frame, text="Search", command=self.guardian_name, pady=2)
        self.button1.grid()


    def guardian_name(self):
        self._name = self.entry.get()
        self.frame.destroy()
        return self.entry.get()
```

EDIT

When I make the recommended changes to the self.frame from the answers, the program runs, but then when I click the button I get this error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\Sailor Moon Hunt\guardian_locator.py", line 25, in guardian_name
    return self.entry.get()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2484, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".45213328.45795632"
```

It appears to be referring to the .get() call, but that was working fine before I made the self.frame changes.  Does anyone know what that error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this code:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self._name = ""
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.grid()
    master.title("GUARDIAN LOCATOR")
```

with the following:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self._name = ""
    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.grid()
    master.title("GUARDIAN LOCATOR")
```

Comment: where are you calling your `guardian_name` function?

Comment: Only inside the button-
`self.button1 = Button(self.frame, text="Search", command=self.guardian_name, pady=2)`

Comment: The window is being called in another file with: 
`root = Tk()
locator = guardian_locator.GuardianLocator(root)
root.mainloop()`

Comment: look at iCodez's edit to his answer, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the `destroy` method.  Instead, Python is complaining that it cannot find the `frame` attribute of `self`.  This is because you forgot to actually make `frame` an instance attribute inside `GuardianLocator.__init__`:

```
self.frame = Frame(master)
self.frame.grid()
```

Notice the `self.` placed before each use of the name `frame`.

Without doing this, the name `frame` is local to the `__init__` method and therefore inaccessible inside `guardian_name` via `self`.

---

**Edit:**

When you do:

```
self.frame.destroy()
```

the `Frame` object referenced by `self.frame` is destroyed and becomes no longer usable.  Moreover, the `Entry` object referenced by `self.entry` is likewise destroyed since it is a child of the frame.  This means that you cannot do:

```
return self.entry.get()
```

because `self.entry` no longer exists at that point.

To avoid this problem, you should be returning `self._name`, which equals `self.entry.get()`:

```
return self._name
```